# Change toolbar button behaviour in android

Tags: android, toolbar, action-button

I implemented a Side Drawer that opens from right to left.
Now I want to replace the default menu icon (3 dots) with another icon.

If the "new icon" is clicked, the side drawer should be opened.

I cant get this to work, and need a bit of help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply add an item in your menu with `showAsAction="always"` and set icon of your desire and add following code in `onOptionsItemSelected`

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if(item.getItemId()==R.id.your item id){
    drawer.open();
    }
}
```